# Javascript Math.ceil and Math.pow returning wrong answer

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know why the exponent and round up functions aren't giving me the correct answers? I've gone through a load of debugging and I can't figure out what I'm doing that's making it's value abnormally large (like 25 orders larger)

```
function CAPEX(){
var initial = document.getElementById("CAPEX").value;
var lifespan = document.getElementById("life").value;
var interest = document.getElementById("IR").value;
var capitalrepayment = initial/lifespan;
var i;
var cap=0;
var expense =0;
for (i=0; i<lifespan;i++){
    expense = capitalrepayment + (initial*interest);
    cap = cap + expense;
    initial = initial - capitalrepayment;
}
denominator = Math.pow((1+interest), lifespan);
console.log(denominator);
return cap;
```

}

I have a similar sort of issue here too where Math.ceil is returning a completely different answer too.

```
 if(selected_scenario == "Divers"){
   var totalTechnicians = numberNeeded * 3;
   var supervisors = totalTechnicians/3;
   var othertechnicians = totalTechnicians-supervisors;
   var boats= Math.ceil((totalTechnicians+numberNeeded)/12);
   divertotal = (numberNeeded*580)+(supervisors*516)+(othertechnicians*276)+(boats*2345)+9230+(boats*20);
}
```

For reference interest is 0.02, lifespan is 25, numberNeeded is 23. I'm reading these values in directly from a form number input.

The denominator should be 1.64 and boats should be 8.

Comment: This: `Math.pow( 1 + "0.02", "25" )` is converting the number `1` to the string `"1"` and concatenating `"0.02"` to give `"10.02"`, then converting it to a number (`10.02`) and raising that to the 25th power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values that you are getting from the DOM are strings. You need to convert them to numbers before you can apply any mathematical operations to them. Try using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`

Comment: Thanks! I thought because the input was a number it was okay, still learning... :)

Comment: I can understand. I must have made the same mistake hundreds of times. You're welcome! :)

Comment: @SultanSinghAtwal you could improve this answer by including some info about how JavaScript operators treats number and strings.